# SSH2 issues wiht Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this code that it seems to be working but it does not.

```
let REMOTE_SSH_HOST = '190.444.01.75:55554'
let REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME = 'olec'
let REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD = 'm3uW4jkbaEwVChklFszpbm4'
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const sshConfig = {
    host: process.env.REMOTE_SSH_HOST,
    //port: 22,
    username: process.env.REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD,
    readyTimeout: 99999,
};
let sftp = new Client();

async function Read(directory) {
    console.log('Read(' + directory + ')');
    const result = await sftp.list(directory);
    for(const sub of result) {
      if (sub['type'] === 'd') {
          await Read(directory + '/ ' + sub['name']);
      }
    }
}

async function main(directory) {
  try{
    const myList = await sftp.list(directory);
    }catch(err){console.log(err)}//NEVER forget to catch
    finally {
        console.log('Closing session...');
        await sftp.end();
        console.log('Session closed.');
    }
}
console.log('Application started');
main('/home/user/path').then(r => {
    console.log('Application ended.');
});
```

I get the error message of:

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
(node:16240) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need something like

```
const sftp = new Client();
await sftp.connect({
  host: hostAddress,
  username: '...',
  privateKey: ...,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using environment variables where you have set consts. (also you are setting consts as lets... don't ever use a let where something will never change.

```
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const REMOTE_SSH_HOST = '190.444.01.75'
const REMOTE_SSH_PORT = '55554';
const REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME = 'olec'
const REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD = 'm3uW4jkbaEwVChklFszpbm4'
const sshConfig = {
    host: REMOTE_SSH_HOST,
    port: REMOTE_SSH_PORT,
    username: REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME,
    password: REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD,
    readyTimeout: 99999,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thnx gonna try this and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of errors on your script that are causing the issue. The main one is that you are not handling errors in your `async` code. You should add a `catch` chain function to your `main` call because, even though you are using a `try/catch` clause inside your `main` function, it doesn't consider the code that runs inside the `finally` block.

On the other hand, your code seems to be failing because you are running `sftp.list` before running `sftp.connect`.

There are a couple of minor errors that could potentially cause problems in your script:

1. The address `190.444.01.75` is not a valid IPv4 address.
2. You should provide default values when reading `env` variables where they make sense.
3. You are not really using the `Read` function yet, but I would suggest you name functions in lower case.
4. You are declaring the variable of the `for-of` loop inside the `Read` function with `const`. It would be best to use `let` instead since the engine will update it on each iteration.

Here is a modified example of your script that works:

```js
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')

/**
 * Global variables
 */
const SSH_CONFIG = {
  host     : process.env.REMOTE_SSH_HOST     || '190.44.1.75:55554',
  port     : process.env.REMOTE_SSH_PORT     || 22,
  username : process.env.REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME || 'olec',
  password : process.env.REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD,
  readyTimeout: 99999,
}
const ROOT = process.env.ROOT || '/home/user/path'

/**
 * Constructors
 */
const sftp = new Client()

/**
 * Main
 */
console.log("Application Started!")
main(ROOT)
  .then ((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err)      => console.error(err))

/**
 * Functions
 */
async function main(directory) {
  let myList
  try {
    await sftp.connect(SSH_CONFIG)
    return await sftp.list(directory)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  } finally {
    console.log('Closing session...')
    await sftp.end()
    console.log('Session closed.')
  }
}
```

And here is how you would call it:

```sh
env REMOTE_SSH_HOST=10.0.0.10 \
env REMOTE_SSH_USERNAME=conatel \
env REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD=C0n4t3lC0n4t3l \
env REMOTE_SSH_PORT=22 \
env ROOT=/home/conatel \
node ssh.js
```

Comment: Thnx that actually helped, though now i get the error:  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  custom: true

Comment: This error sometimes occurs when you are including the `http` or `https` part of the URL. Can you provide the configuration object you are using?

Comment: The sftp server? sure, i can send it to you over email if you´d like